# How to solve dependency when deserializing object graph

Tags: serialization, graph, deserialization

When I deserialize an object graph by restoring all each node and edges by object itself (for object-oriented way), I found there's serious dependency problem.

For example if an object `A` references itself `A`, (self circular reference) it means, it expects itself `A` in *complete original state* while it is restoring. Because it was in that state when it was being serialized.

For self-referencing case, it can be detected because it knows itself is being restored. But if the `A` needs another object `B`, it should expect the other object `B` in complete original state too. If the object `B` also references `A`, now there's circular reference to  `A` again, and it becomes equal problem without knowing the `A` is now being restored. **If `B` wants to use some property of `A` while deserialization, it is not guaranteed to be exist.**

Fundamentally, this problem happens because an object needs complete state of the other objects though itself is in incomplete state. This doesn't make sense. I have thought about dividing restoring process into multiple phases, but it doesn't make any real difference because actually the object will remain in incomplete state until all phases finish.

Can I have some advise or good solution for this problem?

PS.
I started coding this to make some replacement for Cocoa's `NSKeyedArchiver`. So I assumed encoding of object is done by the object itself. (for its internal state) So it could be different with general graph problems. But I can't exclude hidden state that can be get by the object itself...

Answer (score 1):

For later reference...

I studied a lot about this problem after I posted this question. And I realized this problem is fundamentally impossible to solve. (this problem is different with general graph because in my case, each node can hide edges, and each node have to solve edge informations from itself when restoring.)

The core problem is dependency. All each node is depending on its original state which cannot be accessed while deserializing. But if it doesn't depend on non-existing state, it can be serialized completely. And the only way to guarantee this is giving up general graph structure.

So I decided to switch all my data structure into tree structure. This is giving heavy limitation on structure. Because it doesn't have cyclic dependencies, so all nodes can be restored with fully restored sub-node informations.

And I found this. DAG. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph
It's just a directed tree with shared children. I think DAG structure is also fine. Because dependencies can be fully resolved too.

DAG has big limitation. The references cannot be cyclic. I have thought about weak reference concept, but it's same on it needs full original state when it deserializes.
This is huge limitation but I decided trade this off with robust deserialization algorithm. I think shared child reference is enough for me. Actually, the loss of robustness is unacceptable to me, so I decided to go this way.

With these stuffs, I think I can serialize/deserialize my data structure completely.
Thanks for the Internet and the Wikipedia.